# Spring Data Rest Secure HATEOAS link

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Lets say I have an `User` entity with a `ManyToMany` mapping to `UserGroup` entity. If I create repositories for both entities and GET the URI `/users/1`, I get a response like this:

```
{
  "enabled" : true,
  "password" : "xxxxxx",
  "username" : "xxxxxx",
  "credentialsNonExpired" : true,
  "accountNonLocked" : true,
  "accountNonExpired" : true,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:45950/users/1"
    },
    "user" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:45950/users/1"
    },
    "userGroups" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:45950/users/1/userGroups"
    }
  }
}
```

The userGroups link here is really useful.

I can list all `UserGroup`s using the `/userGroups` endpoint.
I would like to protect the `/userGroups` endpoint and `/users/1/userGroups` endpoint using different `spring-security` expressions.

Using the reference here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#security I understand how to secure the first endpoint:

```
public interface UserGroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserGroup, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @Override
    Iterable<T> findAll();
}
```

But how do I secure the second endpoint? Is that even possible currently? Is there some work planned on such a feature. I would love to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem and not found any solution working with Spring's security annotations. As a workaround, I have added something along the line of:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // Whatever config you already have.
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/*/userGroups").hasRole("ADMIN");
}
```

to my implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. While this works, it duplicates the work done when securing the repositories and it is easy to forget adding both the java config and annotations when adding new repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is four years old, but this issue has continued to plague me, and I finally found something that works.

The problem essentially comes down to the fact that Spring HATEOAS has no real security controls; while you can configure the repositories with the appropriate method-level security annotations to prevent access via the REST API, you can't stop the HATEAOS representation model assembler from slurping up any objects it can see.

The solution I found was to expose a `RepresentationModelProcessor` bean for `EntityModel<DomainObject>`s. In your case, this may look something like

```java
@Configuration
public class SecureHateoasConfig {

    public static class UserGroupProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<UserGroup>> {
        @Override
        public EntityModel<UserGroup> process(EntityModel<UserGroup> model) {
            if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication()
                .getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .anyMatch("ROLE_ADMIN"::equals)) {
                return model;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public UserGroupProcessor userGroupProcessor() {
        return new UserGroupProcessor();
    }

}
```

Objects replaced by `null` seem to get filtered out after the normal processing, so embedded entities simply don't include the objects which don't match your filter!

There's probably a much easier way to filter links if you're only doing role-based security, but I'm afraid I don't know it...

Of course, it's possible to extend this considerably, since your secure object processor need not only apply to `EntityModel<UserGroup>`! In my case I have an interface all my secure domain objects implement which can be used to make security decisions, so only one `RepresentationModelProcessor` implementation/bean is required.